# overloaded bracket operation

Tags: c++

Can Bracket operation method  be overloaded for multiple operators?(cpp),I think the Brack operation is a single operator,but I've see the item which say `“Bracket operation method can be overloaded both for single operator and multiple operators”` from a cpp examination paper answer.Could you help me?

Comment: Perhaps the paper means "both single parameter and multiple parameters"?

Answer (score 2):

While you can have multiple overloads of the "subscript" `operator[]`, they must all take precisely one *argument* (and the argument cannot have a default value):

```
struct Foo {
    R1 operator[](T)               { /* ... */ }
    R2 operator[](S const &) const { /* ... */ }
    void operator[](U *)           { /* ... */ }
};
```

The reason is simply one of grammar: The expression `a[n]` is valid, but `a[m,n]` is not a valid binary expression (it is something rather different), and neither is `a[]` valind in that context.

With C++11's initializer lists you can make something like `a[{1,2,3}]` work, though (pending compiler support.)

Comment: If you count the implicit argument you could call that two arguments. Can you overload `[]` outside of a class context?